# How many symmetry planes does a 4D hypercube have?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, symmetry

How many symmetry planes does a 4D hypercube have? For the square and the cube, there are two types of  symmetry lines or planes, the orthogonal ones and the diagonal ones. In n dimension there will be n orthogonal symmetry planes I think, but I'm not sure about the diagonal ones. For the cube, each diagonal symmetry plane is determined by an edge, so one only needs to count the edge and divide it by two since each plane contains a pair of edges. But in four dimension I have trouble visualizing what a plane looks like. If it looks like a cube, then it has 12 edges...

Comment: If you use symmetry lines for the square and symmetry planes for the cube, then for the tesseract you might be thinking of 3-dimensional hyperplanes of symmetry.

Comment: What sort of symmetry are you looking for? Is it the sort of reflection that fixes a three dimensional subspace through the origin, but negates a vector perpendicular to that plane? I reckon there are sixteen of those.

Comment: You are limiting yourself to planes - conceptually you could 3D objects that will support symmetry